# JPA annotations combining one column to another table

Tags: java, sql-server

I have "Table A." Inside Table A there is a "superId" column. It matches the "id" column in "Table B," though this data is not bound to each other. However each "superId" number in Table A is supposed to represent the "id" number in Table B. Also, there is a "name" column in Table B that I want to show on my website when I load it instead of the "superId" number. How would I bind the "name" in Table B to "id" in Table A?

public class A: Part of the code involving the Super_Id for the database for Table A is:

```
'public class A{

@Column(name = "Super_Id")
@Basic(optional = true)
@Expose
private Short superId;

public Short superId() {
    return superId;
}

public void setSuperId(Short superId) {
    this.superId = superId;
}`

'public class B{
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 public void setName(String id) {
    this.name = id == null ? null : id.trim();
}

public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    class b = (Class)obj;
    if(b == null)
        return false;
    if(b.getName().equals(this.name))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create relations between the tables by using `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany` and so on JPA Annotations.